# Can I create a hidden page in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: permissions

Is it possible to 'hide' a page to everyone but a certain user or group of users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you'd go into the library that contains the page and set item level permissions for the page assuming you have the permissions to do so.  Or you could create it in a separate library with unique permissions.

Comment: I created a library but for some reason, I can't edit the permissions; which doesn't make sense since I'm a farm administrator.

Comment: Just being a Farm Admin does not grant you full admin permissions to the site collections.  You need specific permissions on the site collection as well.

Comment: I'm an administrator of the site collection and if I look at the site permissions, I says I have full control.

Comment: Does the Full Control privledge defined for your site collection allow you to Manage Permissions.  Perhaps a policy has altered that?  I don't have a 2010 install to look at to walk you through the GUI to break permissions on the librrary and create new ones. 2007 it was Settings, Library Settings, Advanced Permissions.  Then Actionn, Edit User Permissions, click OK then edit/remove users.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the Audiences feature that allows you to restrict visibility of the page via several different mechanisms, including Groups, distribution lists or other rules based on profile data.

Comment: Audiencing isn't security though.

Comment: True, but he said it only had to be hidden, not necessarily secure

Comment: Yep, that's true I suppose.  I'd rather take the route to ensure security than audience target.  If they don't need to see it, they shouldn't have access to it.

Comment: Understandable, but I'm coming from the perspective of managing a very large SharePoint deployment where per-item security settings are "evil".  They lie out there and multiply in the darkness making the management of site security that much more complex because *nobody* ever remembers that they put that security out there.

Comment: I suppose it also depends on the sensitivity of the content needing to be restricted.  The preferred route would be creating a secured document library and not item level permissions for various files in a library.

Answer (score 0):

If you have publishing turned on you can do this as well by unpublishing the pages, then you can create groups with specific permissions to see pages in various states.